# Virtual call within thread ignores derived class

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

In the following program I have a virtual call from within a thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() { t.join(); }
    virtual void getname() { std::cout << "I am A.\n"; }
    void printname() 
    { 
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() {return ready_to_print; });
        getname(); 
    };
    void set_ready() { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mtx}; ready_to_print = true; cv.notify_one(); }
    void go() { t = std::thread{&A::printname,this}; };

    bool ready_to_print{false};
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::thread t{&A::printname,this};
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int x{4};
};

class C : public B {
    void getname() override { std::cout << "I am C.\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A* a{&c};
    a->getname();
    a->set_ready();
}
```

I was hoping the program would print:

```
I am C.
I am C.
```

But [instead it prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/414273fa419c2c36):

```
I am C.
I am A.
```

In the program I wait until the derived object is fully constructed before I call the virtual member function. However the thread is started before the object is fully constructed.

How can the virtual call be assured?

Comment: What platform do you use? VS2015U3 - "I am C" twice as expected.

Comment: In the link in the question it uses clang, but I [get the same with gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/688e7d3c5107e57a). Also with `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3` I get the same. However if I step through in debug mode in VS2015 then I get "I am C" twice.

Comment: hmm that is strange. I have `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3` . Works fine for both - debug and release.

Comment: You're probably calling `getname` while the object is being **de**structed.

Comment: you may also override `set_ready()` function to ensure the thread is executing correct virtual function.

Comment: @AndreyBuran Hmm. We're getting different results. Even though we have the same compiler it doesn't mean we can't both experience racy stuff with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shown code exhibits a race condition, and undefined behavior.

In your main():

```
C c;

// ...

a->set_ready();
```

Immediately, after `set_ready()` returns, execution thread leaves `main()`. This results in ***immediate destruction*** of `c`, starting with the superclass `C`, and continuing to destroying `B`, then `A`.

`c` is declared in automatic scope. That means that as soon as `main()` returns, it's gone. Joined the choir invisible. It is no more. It ceased to exist. It's an ex-object.

***Your `join()` is in the superclass's destructor***. Nothing stops `C` from being destroyed. The destructor will only pause and wait to join the thread, when the *superclass* gets destroyed, but `C` will start getting destroyed immediately!

Once the `C` superclass is destroyed, its virtual method no longer exists, and invoking the virtual function will end up executing the virtual function in the base class.

Meanwhile the other execution thread is waiting on the mutex and the condition variable. The race condition is that you have no guarantee that the other execution thread will wake up and start executing before the parent thread destroys `C`, which it does immediately after signaling the condition variable.

All that signaling the condition variable gives you is that whatever execution thread is spinning on the condition variable, that execution thread will start executing. Eventually. That thread could, on a very loaded server, start executing seconds later, after its signaled via the condition variable. Its object is gone a long time ago. It was in automatic scope, and `main()` destroyed it (or, rather, the `C` subclass is already destroyed, and `A`'s destructor is waiting to join the thread).

The behavior you are observing is the parent thread managing to destroy the `C` superclass before the `std::thread` gets around to making its virtual method call, after receiving the signal from the condition variable, and unlocking its mutex.

That's the race condition.

Furthermore, executing a virtual method call at the same time the virtual object is being destroyed is already a non-starter. It's undefined behavior. Even if the execution thread ends up in the overridden method, its object is being destroyed by another thread at the same time. You're pretty much screwed, at that point, no matter which way you turn.

Lessons learn: rigging up a `std::thread` to execute something in `this` object is a minefield of undefined behavior. There are ways of doing it correctly, but it's hard.

Comment: Excellent analysis. Still I remain somehow perplexed that when the race condition occurs, the child thread ends up executing the parent method. Ok, it is UB, but a strange one.

Comment: @A.S.H --It's actually fairly simple. This happens when `C`'s destructor already finished. When a subclass gets destroyed, any overridden methods revert to the superclass. Invoking virtual methods in the superclass's destructor is perfectly fine, and it ends up executing the non-overridden methods in the base class. That's what essentially happened here (except the destruction and the execution occured in different threads).

Comment: Yes I see now. Thumbs up.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. By the way, `C` has such nice plumage. It might just be pining.

Comment: Although there's a race condition because it's possible for `set_ready` to make it through and the subsequent notification to finish `printname` to complete before `C` gets destroyed (unlikely, but possible), there's not otherwise undefined behavior.  The behiavior that happens in base class constructors/destructors calling virtual functions is well defined to do exactly what the OP is seeing: the virtual is resolved as if the object is of the type being constructed/destructed.

Comment: What surprizes me is to realize that in the process of destruction from the bottom up, when the subclass is "destroyed", the vtable of the object is reset to that of the super-class in the process. That is why when C was destroyed, the virtual call to `getname` invoked `A::getname`. I wonder if this is specified in the standard or if it is implementation specific. If it is specified in the standard, I have to agree with @CrazyEddie that we should not call it UB.

Comment: @A.S.H - It is specified in the standard.  The virtual function that will be called is the one for the type being created/destroyed.  However, there is still undefined behavior because of the race condition.  `C` might be in the middle of being destroyed when the virtual call is made, so the type would be `C` at the point the virtual is called, but then it could be `A` by the time it's finished...or any variety in between.  So the race does cause UB but not because of the virtual call, but because you have a data race in the process of destruction vs. use.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most likely sequence of events:

- The A part of the object is constructed, which  starts a thread
- The B part of the object is constructed.
- The C part of the object is constructed.
- `getname` is called on the main thread, which prints "I am C!" because it's a C.
- The main thread notifies the other thread (I'll call it the printing thread)
- `main` starts to return.
- The C part of the object is destructed.
- The B part of the object is destructed.
- The A part of the object is destructed... but this blocks until the printing thread exits.
- Now that the main thread is blocked the OS switches to the printing thread.
- The printing thread calls `getname`, which prints "I am A!" because it's an A (with the C and B parts of the object now having been destroyed).
- The printing thread exits
- The main thread wakes up, finishes destroying the A part, and exits the program.

To get the expected behaviour reliably, you need to wait for the printing thread to exit *before* the closing `}` of `main`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will now try to come up with something that will keep `C` alive until `A` can harvest its organs er, I mean, complete the virtual call.

Comment: Excellent answer as well. I think both answers evoke the same sequence for the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are definitive, but don't show a possible fix. Here is the same program with additional variables and waiting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() { t.join(); }
    virtual void getname() { std::cout << "I am A.\n"; }
    void printname()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() {return ready_to_print; });
        getname();
        printing_done = true;
        cv.notify_one();
    };
    void set_ready() { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mtx}; ready_to_print = true; cv.notify_one(); }
    void go() { t = std::thread{&A::printname,this}; };

    bool ready_to_print{false};
    bool printing_done{false};
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::thread t{&A::printname,this};
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int x{4};
};

class C : public B {
public:
    ~C() 
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() {return printing_done; });
    }
    void getname() override { std::cout << "I am C.\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A* a{&c};
    a->getname();
    a->set_ready();
}
```

[Prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dd1e3346806370b):

```
I am C.
I am C.
```